# KeyError: 'A700' in kivy md app when i integerate MDNavigationRail

Tags: python, frontend, kivy, kivymd

hi i am trying to make a dashboard in kivy md and i have a basic app ready now i need to add components in it

[image: the basic dashboard]

now i want to add components like navigation rail etc

following is the goal

[image]

when i try to add items in navigation rail i get err A700

**here is the code for without navigation rail**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons

colors = {
    "Teal": {
        "200": "#18ABA2",
        "500": "#18ABA2",
        "700": "#18ABA2",
    },
    "Red": {
        "200": "#18ABA2",
        "500": "#18ABA2",
        "700": "#18ABA2",
    },
    "Light": {
        "StatusBar": "#18ABA2",
        "AppBar": "#18ABA2",
        "Background": "18ABA2",
        "CardsDialogs": "18ABA2",
        "FlatButtonDown": "18ABA2",
    },
}


KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "Planck"

    MDTabs:
        Tab:
            id: Dashboard
            title: "Dashboard"
            tab_kv_file: "./Screens/Dashboard.kv"

        Tab:
            id: Wallet
            title: "Wallet"
            tab_kv_file: "./Screens/Wallet.kv"

        Tab:
            id: Settings
            title: "Settings"
            tab_kv_file: "./Screens/Settings.kv"

            
<Tab>

    MDIconButton:
        id: icon
        text: "Hello!"
        icon_size: "48sp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
'''


class Tab(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    '''Class implementing content for a tab.'''

    icon = ObjectProperty()
    


class Planck(MDApp):
    icons = list(md_icons.keys())[15:18]

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.colors = colors
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Red"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    # def on_start(self):
    #     for name_tab in self.icons:
    #         tab = Tab(title=name_tab, icon=name_tab)
    #         self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(tab)


Planck().run()
```

**here is the code with navigation rail that works without items**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.navigationrail import MDNavigationRail, MDNavigationRailItem

colors = {
    "Teal": {
        "200": "#18ABA2",
        "500": "#18ABA2",
        "700": "#18ABA2",
    },
    "Red": {
        "200": "#18ABA2",
        "500": "#18ABA2",
        "700": "#18ABA2",
    },
    "Light": {
        "StatusBar": "#18ABA2",
        "AppBar": "#18ABA2",
        "Background": "18ABA2",
        "CardsDialogs": "18ABA2",
        "FlatButtonDown": "18ABA2",
    },
}

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal"

    MDNavigationRail:
        id: nav_rail

        

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Planck"

        MDTabs:
            Tab:
                id: Dashboard
                title: "Dashboard"
                tab_kv_file: "./Screens/Dashboard.kv"

            Tab:
                id: Wallet
                title: "Wallet"
                tab_kv_file: "./Screens/Wallet.kv"

            Tab:
                id: Settings
                title: "Settings"
                tab_kv_file: "./Screens/Settings.kv"

<Tab>
    MDIconButton:
        id: icon
        text: "Hello!"
        icon_size: "48sp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
'''

class Tab(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    icon = ObjectProperty()

class Planck(MDApp):
    icons = []

    def build(self):
        # Ensure proper theme initialization
        self.theme_cls.colors = colors
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Red"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Planck().run()
```

**and adding items doesnt work**

```
KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal"

    MDNavigationRail:
        id: nav_rail

        MDNavigationRailItem:
            text: "dash"
            icon: "assets/Control Panel.svg"

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Planck"

        MDTabs:
            Tab:
                id: Dashboard
                title: "Dashboard"
                tab_kv_file: "./Screens/Dashboard.kv"

            Tab:
                id: Wallet
                title: "Wallet"
                tab_kv_file: "./Screens/Wallet.kv"

            Tab:
                id: Settings
                title: "Settings"
                tab_kv_file: "./Screens/Settings.kv"

<Tab>
    MDIconButton:
        id: icon
        text: "Hello!"
        icon_size: "48sp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
'''
```

Comment: Try changing your `icon` to a standard icon name instead of an image file. See if that removed the error.